# write EPIPE UML in VS Code

Tags: uml, graphviz, plantuml

Hey guys I'm new to UML and trying to draw on visual code. From help of google I downloaded plantuml extension, java enviornment, graphviz. But with this either google isn't helping. If anyone has idea about this error I'll really appreciate help.

Error image:

[image: Error Screenshot]

```
@startuml Hello World
    actor Customer
    Customer -> "login()" : username & password
    "login()" -> Customer : session token
    activate "login()"
    Customer -> "placeOrder()" : session token, order info
    "placeOrder()" -> Customer : ok
    Customer -> "logout()"
    "logout()" -> Customer : ok
    deactivate "login()"
@enduml
```

Comment: Rather than a screen shot post the content of the error log.

Comment: Hamza Nadeem you came but without reacting on my answer, does that solve your problem ?

Comment: yeh i got my problem solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But with this either google isn't helping

If I search for `vscode error write epide plantuml` using *google* I find [qjebbs/vscode-plantuml](https://github.com/qjebbs/vscode-plantuml/issues/330#issuecomment-674576713) giving a fix under Windows :

> I've managed to resolve it by adding java to my path (C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_221\bin). After restarting VSCode, it seems to be working fine.

So try it if you didn't already.

If you are not on Windows please indicate your OS though the tags on the question

---

Out of that very probably the sequence diagram you define is not the one you want, for instance some messages must be answer, and the alone *OccurrenceSpecification* is wrong.

The diagram produced by your definition is :

[image]

Comment: It merely looks like the messages are on top in the name compartment where the object name should be? So it's a bit of a weird output :-/

Comment: @qwerty_so all is wrong in the diagram. But the initial problem is elsewhere

Comment: I thought so. It should probably be pointed out more prominently so to prevent others from copying this way.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
After installing java, and add java to the path (java 11 on windows 10), it worked